How to view the json data for a document if you have only the document reference for that document?
I only have the document reference for a document. From that reference, I want to retrieve the data stored for that document in firebase. I am using flutter.

Just use the get() method of that reference:
docRef
.get()
.then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if(documentSnapshot.exists){
     print(documentSnapshot.data());
    }
  }
});


It works. And if I want to reassign one of the fields what should I do?

Or to view each of the element individually, what should I do?

@Matt just treat data() as Map<String,dynamic> . if you need to access specific field print(documentSnapshot.data()['MyField']) and of course you can iterate over that map through forEach and do whatever wanted.
